# Functions of the form $\int_a^x f(t) dt$ that are commonly used.

Tags: calculus

I am a graduate student and teaching assistant, and I am teaching Calc 1 for the first time. In a few weeks I will be covering the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  I'm using James Stewart's Calculus textbook, and I was hoping to give students several "real world" examples of functions of the form $g(x)=\int_a^x f(t) dt$ to make the first part of the FTC more accessible.  Stewart gives one example, the Fresnel function

$$S(x)=\int_0^x \sin (\pi t^2/2)$$

which is (apparently) used in the theory of the diffraction of light waves.  But I was hoping for more examples from physics, chemistry, etc.  Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Possibly the beginner example is $\ln x = \int_1^x \frac{dx}{x}$, followed by proving it has the properties of a logarithm.

Comment: Six answers have been posted but I'm the only person who's up-voted the question.

Answer (score 7):

$$
\Phi(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-z^2/2}\,dz
$$

This is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution, seen in every course on statistics.  Physicists often talk about the "error function", in which $z^2$ appears instead of $z^2/2$ (and then the normalizing constant is different).  That's trivially equivalent to this one, but with this version, the standard deviation is $1$.

Abraham de Moivre considered this function in the 18th century while thinking about a coin-tossing problem.  Suppose you toss a coin 1800 times.  What is the probability that the number of heads is in the range (say) $\{886,\ldots, 908\}$?  An exact answer is computationally far too expensive, but the integral above does it.

The derivative of $\Phi$ is conventionally denoted $\varphi$.

The one seen tabulated in the back of every statistics textbook is $\Phi$.

Comment: Used to be computationally far too expensive, but nowadays it's easy for any computer algebra system.

Comment: @RobertIsrael : True: there are a zillion software packages that hand you values of $\Phi$ and $\Phi^{-1}$ instantly.

Comment: @RobertIsrael : Oh: I see.  You were referring to the thing that _I_ called computationally too expensive.

Comment: How could I forget this! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In cartography in the year 1599 the following problem arose.  Mercator wanted a map of the world on which compass bearings on the earth correspond to those on the map.  E.g. $13^\circ$ east of north on the surface of the earth corresponds to $13^\circ$ counterclockwise from straight up on the map, at every point.  Going through a bit of geometry, it is found that at latitude $\theta$, the ratio of distance on the map to distance on the earth has to be proportional to $\sec\theta$.  That implies that the location of points on the map at latitude $\theta$ should be at the following distance from the equator:
$$
\int_0^\theta \sec\alpha\,d\alpha.
$$
Evaluating this integral remained a famous unsolved problem for (I think?) more than half a century.

Comment: See e.g. http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m103/mercator/mercator.html

Answer (score 2):

The incomplete Beta function
$$
x\mapsto \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)} \int_0^x u^{\alpha-1}(1-u)^{\beta-1}\,du\quad\text{ for }0\le x\le 1
$$
arises in probability and statistics.  When the two parameters $\alpha$, $\beta$ are positive integers, then the incomplete Beta function is a polynomial function, but it probably cannot be expressed more simply than by this integral.

Answer (score 1):

The [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^x e^{-t^2}\ dt$ has many applications, especially in probability and statistics, and from there to physics.

Answer (score 0):

In quantum mechanics the method of time dependent perturbation theory yield integrals like this. For instance the probability amplitude for a transition from the ground state of an atom to some higher excited state due to an eternally applied oscillating electric field is given by an integral like,

$$ \phi_{0 \rightarrow n} = \frac{1}{i\hbar} \int_0^T H'_{0n} e^{i\omega_{0n} t} dt $$

Answer (score 0):

In probability, if the random variable is continuous, rather than discrete, then

$P(a \leq X \leq b) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,dx$ where $f$ has a lebesgue integral.

The cumulative distribution function to a continuous random variable is $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(u)\,du$

This is very widely used in just about any question or real life scenario where continuous probability is involved.

The very best of luck on your new job.

Answer (score 0):

[Sine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) has such form:

$$\operatorname{Si}(x)=\int_0^x\frac{\sin t}{t}\text{d}t.$$

Similar form is for the [cosine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html), although it's not quite the same. See also [logarithmic integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral), [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), I'm sure you could find more.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need any examples?

In my opinion, FTC is the most important part in Calculus because how it unites the other two parts (dir/int).

The derivative-form of FTC implies that the overall properties of a function (integral) is decided by the domestic properties (derivative).

The integral-form of FTC of FTC indicates that the domestic properties are regulated by the overall properties.

With FTC, it's much easier to do integral with anti-derivatives. It's an example to tell the students how the advancements in mathematics make it easier to solve problems.

I don't think it's needed to make the "first part" of FTC accessible. Actually FTC is FTC and the two so-called parts are essentially the same. They are just represented in two different forms. Similarly, differentiation and integration are essentially the same. So do the two mean value theorems.

Comment: While it might not be "needed" to make the FTC 1 more accessible, I feel that some discussion of what the function $\int_a^x f(x)dx$ is will be useful before just writing down the statement of the FTC.